# Validation-messages inside a FormRequest for an integer-array are not accepted

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using FormRequest to validate, also overriding messages function to set custom messages.
Somehow, I can't get integer-array validation to work. This is where I'm at:

This is what my request should look like:

```
// ACCEPTED: 
{
    "name": "my name",
    "items": [20, 7, 1, 2]
}
// REJECTED
{
    "name": "Meine neue Kampagne",
    "items": ["ANY STRING HERE", 1, 2]
}
```

So I want my items to only be an array of integers. These are my rules, which are fully working:

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|max:191',
    'items' => 'array',
    'items.*' => 'int|exists:jobpostings,id'
];
```

So far, I tried the following (all found in online tutorials):

```
return [
    'items.*.int' => "item is not int",
];

return [
    'items.*[
        'int' => "item is not int"
    ]
];
```

They all just gave the common "The items.0 must be an integer." message.

Can anyone help me maybe?

Here is the complete FormRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Campaign;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateCampaignRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:191',
            'items' => 'array',
            'items.*' => 'int|exists:items,id'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => __('campaign.createCampaign.name_required'),
            'name.max' => __('campaign.createCampaign.name_max'),
            'items.array' => __('campaign.createCampaign.items_array'),
            'items.*.int' => __('campaign.createCampaign.items_*_int'),
            'items.*.exists' => __('campaign.createCampaign.items_*_exists'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: would you post the entire `FormRequest`?

Comment: @HafezDivandari sure, I edited the question! Tried to keep it smaller! Thanks for the comment!